# Writing a thin object proxy by implementing the __get__ descriptor

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create a think proxy using the [`__get__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) descriptor  over a certain type of data so that it can be used conveniently by client code (best shown with an example):

```
class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.val

class Container(object):
    x = Value(1)
    y = [ Value(2), Value(3) ]

c = Container()
assert c.x == 1
assert c.y[0] == 2 # fails.
```

Now, I mostly see why it fails, so I'm wondering if theres a better way to achieve my goal which is wrap up the data so that when the client accesses it they simply have to access the Value object directly (in reality, the `__get__` method would do something with `self.val` before returning it)

### Details

The actual case I'm trying to tackle is utility code to assist in writing [PageObjects](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) & PageElements for selenium test cases. What I want to provide is a clean and simple way for test authors to write PageObjects of the form:

```
class MyLogin(PageObject):
    username_text_box = PageElement(By.ID, "username")
    password_text_box = PageElement(By.ID, "password")
    submit_button = PageElement(By.CLASS_NAME, "login-button")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://mypage.com")
login_page = MyLogin(driver)
login_page.username_text_box.send_keys("username01")
login_page.password_text_box.send_keys("XXXX")
login_page.submit_button.click()
```

I'm trying to encapsulate the business of fetching the actual [WebElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) inside the PageElement class and I want to allow the client to have access to the WebElement once they access the PageElement Object. Being able to have lists, dictionaries assists in making the PageObject instance clearer and to group related PageElements.

Comment: As you see, descriptors don't work except as class attributes.  If you could provide more detail, it would be easier to find a solution for you.

Comment: The usual way to make a proxy object in python is to emulate proxied object's behavior using `__getattr__` (and possibly `__setattr__`). Your way won't work except in new-style class' member case.

Comment: Why not try **y = Value((2,1))** instead of **y = [ Value(2), Value(3) ]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled with an implementation which both jsbueno & python_noob were approaching. However both their implementations don't meet my criteria of allowing test authors to write simple declarative page object.

```
import inspect
import weakref
class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.val

def get_value_from_proxy(obj, inst):
    if isinstance(obj, Value):
        return obj.__get__(inst, inst.__class__)
    else:
        return obj 

class ValueList(list):
    def __init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        list.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.instance = weakref.ref(instance)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return get_value_from_proxy(list.__getitem__(self, idx), self.instance() )

class ValueDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.instance = weakref.ref(instance)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return get_value_from_proxy(dict.__getitem__(self, key), self.instance() )

class BaseContainer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for el in inspect.getmembers(self):
            if isinstance(el[1],list):
                setattr(self, el[0], ValueList(self, el[1]))
            elif isinstance(el[1],dict):
                setattr(self, el[0], ValueDict(self, el[1]))


class Container(BaseContainer):
    x = Value(1)
    y = [ Value(2), Value(3) ]
    z = {"test":Value(4)}

c = Container()
assert c.x == 1
assert c.y[0] == 2
assert c.z["test"] == 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an additional proxy if you want to proxy the array accessor as well. Here's an example using property() for x since it's just an attribute, and an array proxy accessor for y.

self._*x and self.*_y are the internal, private accessors for the true Value's

```
import functools

class array_proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, accessor):
        self.accessor = accessor

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.accessor(key)

class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = Value(1)
        self.__y = [Value(2), Value(3)]
        self.y = array_proxy(functools.partial(Container.get_y_element, self))

    @property
    def x(self):
        val = self.__x.val
        # do stuff with val
        return val

    def get_y_element(self, key):
        val = self.__y[key].val
        # do stuff with val
        return val


c = Container()
assert c.x == 1
assert c.y[0] == 2
```

If you can force the other people to use get_y_element directly then it's a bit simpler to proxy it, and it's more explicit to the user about what is happening when they access it.

Answer (score 1):

Python_noob's answer is good.

It can be made simpler and less generic - for easier understanding.

The matter is the descriptor protocol just "works" with class attributes. In the example snippet you put, the class attribute is the list `y`, not the `Value` objects inside it.

If you just implement can create a sequence class that replaces `__getitem__` with a call to the item's `__get__` you should get the behavior you want:

```
class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.val

class ValueList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return list.__getitem__(self,item).__get__(self.instance, self.instance.__class__)

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.y = ValueList(self.__class__.y)
        self.y.instance = self
        # ...

    x = Value(1)
    y = [ Value(2), Value(3) ]

c = Container()
assert c.x == 1
assert c.y[0] == 2 # works.
```

Note that the sequence class has no way to authomatically know to which instance it belongs - so this has to be explicitly set at instantiation.  (Your Value in the example would suffer from the same fate at its `__init__` method: it does not know its Container instance )